# How to send messages to dead letter queue after client error?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sns

Amazon SNS does not send messages to Dead Letter Queue (DLQ) when the subscription-http-endpoint returns a client-side-error.

I have a SNS topic which is sending notifications to a https-endpoint. I also attached a Dead Letter Queue to it and enabled delivery status logging.

When notifications can't reach the endpoint because of network timeout or a server-side-error (e.g. 500) from the endpoint, the notification gets into the retry-policy and after the configured amount of retries, the notification is sent to the DLQ. This works fine! This is how the logs looks like:

```
{
    "notification": {
        "messageMD5Sum": "1234",
        "messageId": "123-456-789",
        "topicArn": "arn:aws:sns:eu-west-1:1234:mysnstopic",
        "timestamp": "2021-06-08 15:15:21.454"
    },
    "delivery": {
        "deliveryId": "84b16cc6-09bd-5186-a6cb-35ff8274dc9d",
        "redrivePolicy": "{\n  \"deadLetterTargetArn\": \"arn:aws:sqs:eu-west-1:1234:mydlq\"\n}\n",
        "destination": "https://my-endpoint.xy/",
        "providerResponse": "Socket timeout in HttpClient",
        "dwellTimeMs": 30137,
        "attempts": 3
    },
    "status": "FAILURE"
}
```

But sometimes it happens, that the https-endpoint responds with a client-side-error (e.g. 404). In this case SNS logs the notification as "SUCCESS" and is finished. It does not go into retry-policy (which is OK) and it does not send the notification to the DLQ (not OK). Logs looks like this:

```
{
    "notification": {
        "messageMD5Sum": "1234",
        "messageId": "123-456-789",
        "topicArn": "arn:aws:sns:eu-west-1:1234:mysnstopic",
        "timestamp": "2021-06-08 15:24:46.146"
    },
    "delivery": {
        "deliveryId": "111-222-333",
        "redrivePolicy": "{\n  \"deadLetterTargetArn\": \"arn:aws:sqs:eu-west-1:1234:mydlq\"\n}\n",
        "destination": "https://my-endpoint.xy/",
        "providerResponse": "Not Found",
        "dwellTimeMs": 202,
        "attempts": 1,
        "statusCode": 404
    },
    "status": "SUCCESS"
}
```

In the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/sns-dead-letter-queues.html#why-do-message-deliveries-fail) it says

> In general, message delivery fails when Amazon SNS can't access a subscribed endpoint due to a client-side or server-side error. When Amazon SNS receives a client-side error, or continues to receive a server-side error for a message beyond the number of retries specified by the corresponding retry policy, Amazon SNS discards the message—unless a dead-letter queue is attached to the subscription.

According to the doc, I expect that notifications which gets a 404 will be not SUCCESS but FAILURE and are sent to the DLQ. How can I configure it to have the desired effect?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry if I'm a bit later to answer this but according to the AWS Docs:

> Make sure that your endpoint responds to the HTTP POST message from
> Amazon SNS with the appropriate status code. The connection will time
> out in 15 seconds. If your endpoint does not respond before the
> connection times out or if your endpoint returns a status code outside
> the range of 200-4xx SNS will consider the delivery of the message as
> a failed attempt.

So you need the endpoint to return a `503 Service Unavailable` etc... for them to be registered as undeliverable in SNS